# ServiceStack v4.0.24.0 Google OAuth on Azure fails with 502

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, servicestack

After upgrading to ServiceStack to 4.0.24.0, I started receiving this below error when trying to login using Google OAuth.

[image]

The same works locally on my dev machine.
Has anything changed since the 4.0.21.0?

- The site is hosted on Azure as you can see from the address bar.
- I've the licensed version of SS
- Google OAuth Callback url is correctly registered http://somesite.azurewebsites.net/auth/GoogleOAuth
- Using ServiceStack.Authentication.OAuth2 4.0.24.0

Comment: Hi - did you have any luck with the problem, i'm still not able to login with Google.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty strange problem, but recently did some digging and here is what I found. It seems that Azure Websites doesn't like the `HttpResult` returning from the method `Authenticate` on the `OAuth2Provider`.

**Important to note:** This problem is only present when hosted on Azure Websites. ServiceStack OAuth2Providers (4.0.24 to 4.0.40) work as expected when hosted else where.

*Specifically*, it doesn't like the `Content-Length` header being set when returning a `HttpResult`. I'm not sure exactly why this is the case as it works locally and when deployed to my own IIS host on AWS.

I've [created a repository](https://github.com/Layoric/AzureWebsiteTesting) you can deploy yourself that highlights this issue.

Azure Websites seem to be interpreting this response differently than on a standard IIS setup (eg, installed via Web Installer on a clean VM) which seems to be causing the problem.

One (not very nice) work around would be to use a `GlobalResponseFilter` stripping out `Content-Length` header of the **only** the `GoogleOAuth2Provider` response.

I've tested this out and indeed worked as expected and I was able to login using Google OAuth. Here is an example of using a GlobalResponseFilter to work around this problem.

```
GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
{
    if (!req.PathInfo.EndsWith("/auth/GoogleOAuth", true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        return;
    }
    HttpResult httpResult = dto as HttpResult;
    if (httpResult != null && httpResult.Headers.ContainsKey("Content-Length"))
    {
        httpResult.Headers.Remove("Content-Length");
    }
});
```

Would be great if someone can point out *why* Azure websites does this.

Hope this helps.